# unable to run newly compiled openssl

Tags: linux, openssl

I have a new Linux install ([Ubuntu Mini Remix 16.04](https://web.archive.org/web/20170430000117/http://www.ubuntu-mini-remix.org/)) and I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
cd openssl
./config --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl
make
make test
sudo make install
```

I then typed in `openssl` in the CLI and got this message:

```
openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while loading shared libraries: /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828083/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-usr-local-lib64-libssl-so-1-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe /usr/local/lib is not in /etc/ld.so.conf?? If it is just try to run 'ldconfig' as root with no params, if it's not just add it and run 'ldconfig'.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
do "which openssl" to confirm you're looking at the correct copy.  do "ldd openssl" to get a list of what dynamic libraries it's expecting.  Given the error you got there should be an error in the LDD output showing it can't find libssl.so.

Your "make install" may have simply left out "ldconfig".  Do "ldconfig" to get the system to refresh it's information on where shared libraries are (it gets that from /etc/ld.so.conf and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/.

You can use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to force it to use a certain directory to search for shared libraries, that often fixes this error.