# Can't Make Solana Tokens, Ubuntu

Tags: solana

spl-token: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have tried everything I can think of. Searched high and low. Seems Ubuntu discontinues the old libssl.

can't do anything with Solana because of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while loading shared libraries: /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828083/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-usr-local-lib64-libssl-so-1-1)

Answer (score 0):

Found IT
GO TO https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libssl1.1/download
MAYBE FIND YOUR EXACT DISTRO BUT THIS IS NORMAL 64 UBUNTU. download this, yes it is safe. open file as install. presto, it works!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).